# How to iterate over files in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

I am trying to move files from one folder to another and below is the PowerShell code that I have come up with:

```
$folder = 'C:\test'
$filter = '*.*'                             # <-- set this according to your requirements
$destination = 'C:\Folder1'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 #$UNI_PRINT = Select-String -Path C:\Test\*.Print_Job -Pattern "SATO"\\
 $file = Get-Content -Path $folder
 $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "SATO"}

if ($containsWord -contains $true)
{
    Write-Host Contains String
    Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
else
{
    Write-Host Not Contains String
}
}
```

The C:\test folder is getting continuously 5 to 6 files with an extension .Print_Job.

So I have written Filecreated event so that I can continuously monitor the folder to check if a file has been created or not.

Inside that I want to read the content of each file received before moving it based on below criteria.

- If the File content contains Motorola, that file should get moved to Folder1
- If the File Content contains SATO, that file should get moved to Folder2.
- If the File Content contains Zebra, that file should get moved to Folder3.

How can I do this in poweshell.

Looking forward to your solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work....

```
$directory_source = '<path>'
$directory_target_motorola = '<path>'
$directory_target_sato = '<path>'
$directory_target_zebra = '<path>'

$files = $(ls $directory)
foreach ($file in $files) {
  if ( $(gc $file | Select-String "motorola" -Quiet) ) {
    mv -Path $file.Fullname -Destination $directory_target_motorola
  } elseif ( $(gc $file | Select-String "sato" -Quiet) ) {
    mv -Path $file.Fullname -Destination $directory_target_sato 
  } elseif ( $(gc $file | Select-String "zebra" -Quiet) ) {
    mv -Path $file.Fullname -Destination $directory_target_zebra 
  }
}
```

Note, I have not tried to run this.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Applies to requirements now.

- a RegEx with an or condition is used within Select-String and the
  found files and matched Value are stored in a hash table.
- Finally the hash table is iterated, destination folders evaluated with `Get-Variable`, created if not present and the file moved (with an optional -whatif)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\04\27\SO_50067617.ps1
$directory_source   = '.\*'
$directory_target_motorola = 'c:\test\folder1'
$directory_target_sato =     'c:\test\folder2'
$directory_target_zebra =    'c:\test\folder3'

$FilePattern = @{}
Get-ChildItem $directory_source -File | Select-String "(MOTOROLA|SATO|ZEBRA)" |
  ForEach-Object {
      $FilePattern[$_.FileName] = $_.Matches.Value
  }

$FilePattern.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  $Target = (Get-Variable "directory_target_$($_.Value)").Value
  If (!(Test-Path $Target)) { md $Target }
  mv $_.Name $Target -whatif
}
```